# Why am I getting Bad Request trying to POST a GraphQL query from a C# handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphql, httptaskasynchandler

I'd like to use a web service or a handler to send a mutation to a GraphQL API. I've got GraphQL code working in Postman and a console app. But whenever I try similar code in a service or handler, all I can get is a 400 Bad Request. Currently trying in a HttpTaskAsyncHandler:

```
public class AsyncHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler {

    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string result = await GoSC();
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }

    public async Task<string> GoSC()
    {
        // Define the cancellation token.
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "*******");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "MyApp");

        string uri = "https://theAPI.com/graphql";

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
        {
            var queryObject = new
            {
                query = @"query {query{currentOrgId}}"
            };            

            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(
                                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject),
                                            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json"))
            {
                request.Content = stringContent;

                using (var response = await client
                    .SendAsync(request,
                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead,
                            cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    //string resString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                    string resString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //string resString = await response.Content
                    return resString;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried everything for the HttpRequestMessage content from straight strings to serialized Json. Always the Bad Request.
Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated!
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we were running an http to https redirect on the web server that was somehow interfering with the API. It took moving the handler to my own pc to figure it out.